# DB2 for z/OS: node comparison in XQuery

Tags: db2

We have a view as below

```
CREATE VIEW  CORE_V_LOG_OUTPUT AS 
select SERIAL, xtab.OUTPUT_ROW, xtab.OUTPUT_NAME, xtab.OUTPUT_VALUE 
FROM bizzcore_log, XMLTable('declare namespace s="http://xml.snow.com/bizz/logging"; 
for $i in $x/s:Info/s:Output/s:rowValues/s:value 
return document { <row> <num>{count($i/../../s:rowValues[. << $i/../.]) +1} </num> 
<col>{$i/../../s:columnNames/s:name[count($i/../*[. << $i]) +1]}</col> 
{if (($i/.)[1]/@value) then <val>{ string(($i/.)[1]/@value)} </val> 
else <dummy></dummy>} </row> }' 
PASSING Info as "x" COLUMNS OUTPUT_NAME VARCHAR(256) PATH '/row/col', 
OUTPUT_VALUE VARCHAR(256) PATH '/row/val',OUTPUT_ROW INT PATH '/row/num') xtab;
```

We can create the view on DB2 LUW and DB2/400 successfully. But creating the view on DB2 V10 for z/OS will get below error:

SQLCODE=-16031, SQLSTATE=10509, SQLERRMC=node comparison

So node comparison is not supported by DB2 for z/OS. Now my question is how can I write the view in other ways using XQuery (or not)?

Please show me some light on this, appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apprantely DB2 V10 for z/OS doesn't support node comparison for now. So no easy solution for this issue.